# Flow datatable to show data points from different objects/fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, lightning-datatable, datatable

[image]

I am trying to use FLOW data table element - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_data_table.htm&type=5 to display columns data like above screenshot.

Given the column data would come from different object and there is a need to have a free text , is this even possible out of the box datatable without no use of LWC/Apex?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: i pushed for this with the Flow PM at DF 22 and was acknowledged as useful for read-only (via an apex custom type). For now, you need to use a proxy record collection of a single SObjectType that has the fields you need. Given the lookup field; the LWC option might be a better choice

Comment: Does the proxy rec collection sobject should be of type WorkOrder? I am not sure how to add the 2nd column data which is coming from completely different object.

Comment: If the data is already coming from an object and its related objects, you may be able to use cross-object formula fields to bring all the data into the primary object.

Comment: The data comes from un related object. It fetches the Account using a Query. Although there is an Account lookup on WorkOrder. But it will be empty. Those rules would decide what goes into that lookup field on WO.

Comment: the proxy object approach assumes there are custom fields or existing fields you can use as proxies for the unrelated object - I'm not saying this will work for you but if you want to use the Data Table, you have to give it a record collection variable - these need not be actual records in the database